# Deleting an element from an array

Tags: c++

I want to delete an element from an array.I have an array of ints from 1 - 9. My algorithm searches through a row, if a number in the row matches a number in the array, it deletes the number in the array. What is the most efficient algorithm to do this with? I was thinking of a linked list because I could simply shorten the list, but it might get confusing later on and it may not be as efficient as an array.

Comment: Are you asking for the most efficient algorithm or container? They're two separate things.

Comment: Use `std::vector` unless you have a reason not to. In most cases the performance of `std::vector` is better than the performance of `std::list`

Comment: You cannot delete elements from an array of `int`. They have fixed size, so they always contain the same number of elements.

Comment: I was thinking about placing a 0 in the array if they match. I haven't done c++ in over 8 months so I forget how to program in this language lol. I've also never used std::list, I would just create a struct list and use that. This is for the naked cells of Sudoku.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method is to use another container container *empty / full* flags for each slot in the array.  Otherwise each element has to be moved up a slot.

Answer (score 0):

There are simply way to many variables here to be able to give a good answer.

From your description, you have 2 data structures that each has a list of values and you want to delete all of the values from the first structure that are in the second structure. What kind of structure is the second structure? do you have control over it? Is it something that can be easily and quickly searched like a set or unordered_set or is it something that has to be iterated over to find a value like a linked list? Does the data structure that you're deleting from need to be kept in ascending order?

Ideally, one of these containers is going to have to be iterated over from start to finish and the other is going to be something that is quickly searchable. You want the container you're going to delete from to have a fast delete time. If the array needs to be kept in order, then deleting from an array is a time consuming process that requires either A: moving every elements from the point of deletion onwards back one and then tracking the actual length of the array or B: copying the contents of the array to a new array that is missing that element. Really, there just is not enough information here to give you a good answer about what algorithms or containers are best for your task.